# Bind SolidColorBrush in Resource Dictionary to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, viewmodel

I have a resource dictionary of colors with the following line

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MainProgramBlue" Color="{Binding MainProgramColor}"/>
```

I then have this resource dictionary merged into the App.xaml file, etc so in my view I can use MainProgramBlue as a StaticResource.  Everything works if I actually put the color into the dictionary like the following color

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightGrey" Color="#D5D5D5"/>
```

But I want to bind the color to a view model like so

```
public class ThemeViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    public ThemeViewModel()
    {
        MainProgramColor = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom( "#F79218" ));
    }

    private SolidColorBrush mMainProgramColor;
    /// <summary>
    ///
    /// </summary>
    public SolidColorBrush MainProgramColor
    {
        get
        {
            return mMainProgramColor;
        }
        set
        {
            mMainProgramColor = value;
            Notify( "MainProgramColor" );
        }
    }

}
```

But the view model doesn't seem to set the MainProgramBlue to the color I want.  The binding isn't working.  Even though if I do this

```
<Grid Background="{Binding MainProgramColor}">
```

The binding works and my grid background is set to the color in the ViewModel.  Why won't the view model binding work in the colors.xaml resource dictionary?  Is it even possible to do that?

I have a program that uses about 5 colors throughout and right now they are hardcoded, but I want to bind them all to properties so the use can set their own colors and themes and I would like to bind them in the resource dictionary rather than bind them every single place in the xaml...thoughts?

Comment: I think I know why...you can't bind x:Key data can you?

Comment: if you set the datacontext for your view correctly then ideally <Grid Background="{Binding MainProgramColor}"> should work.. can you check if you are getting any binding errors and how are you setting the datacontext for the view?

Comment: Yes, the <Grid Background="{Binding MainProgramColor}"> works correctly, but I was trying to get <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MainProgramBlue" Color="{Binding MainProgramColor}"/> to work which isn't possible I found out.